# What's Yii's backwards-compatibility been like so far?

Tags: php, frameworks, yii

With the release of Yii 1.1.7 and the possibility of finally returning database results as objects, I've finally decided to dive headfirst into Yii's documentation.

Coming from CodeIgniter, and seeing how compatibility between 1.7.x and 2.x was fairly pain free (only renaming a few classes), and also knowing that there is no compatibility between major versions of Kohana, I'm wondering if Yii is considered a friendly framework for people like myself who like to upgrade to newest versions as they come out, or will I be stuck with the choice of either staying on an old version or rewriting large parts of my existing code to be able to upgrade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have started with 1.1.X version so I cannot speak about compatibility between major version (eq : 1.0.x to 1.1.x).

Since I have started yii I have never had any problem to upgrade. As @Chux said just simply overwriting the framework folder.

About major version, yii off website say :

> Our next major release Yii 2.0 will be
>   a complete rewrite of the framework on
>   top of PHP 5.3.0+. **It will not be
>   fully compatible with 1.1.x**. **Note:** We
>   have yet to start developing Yii 2.0.
>   The earliest possible 2.0 alpha
>   release may be in Dec 2011, but we
>   cannot guarantee it.

Comment: Thanks, I must have misunderstood when they mentioned 2.0. I always assumed there'd be a 1.2 - 1.9 first!

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty new to the framework (3 months, two projects). I've been since 1.1.4 i think, and i have update my project by simply overwriting the framework folder.

I guess that when will be a major change (1.2?) this will be not (maybe) so easy.

Comment: Next major change seems like it will be 2.0. Can't really expect compatibility when the actual version digit changes (unless you're talking about CodeIgniter, it seems).